# Creating DMG and uploading to internet is creating an error

Tags: linux, macos, centos, dmg

I created dmg of three files named `file1`, `file2`, `file3`. I kept these three in one directory

and ran this command in the directory where we kept our three files

```
dd if=/dev/zero of="example.dmg" bs=1M count=10; hformat -l "example" ./"example.dmg"
```

A dmg file will be formed in our directory. next go to /usr/sbin from there run and then

1. `hmount /directorypath/example.dmg`
2. `hcopy /directorypath/file1 example:`
3. `hcopy /directorypath/file2 example:`
4. `hcopy /directorypath/file3 example:`
5. `humount`

and then copy this file in to your mac system and open the dmg file,you will find all your three files in it.

till now it is good, but once i upload it in to internet and from there if i download it.I am getting an error as

```
There may be a problem with this disk image. Are you sure you want to open it?

Opening this disk image may make your computer less secure or cause other problems.
```

Comment: how did you get the error? maybe it's just an caution from your browser.

Comment: There may be a problem with this disk image. Are you sure you want to open it?

Opening this disk image may make your computer less secure or cause other problems.                                                 This was the message i was seeing.And i dont want this when i submit my dmg to the end customer

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/118487/dmg-mounting-warning-message-says-it-may-make-computer-less-secure-or-cause-oth according to this url, it says that executing `fsck` might solve the problem.

Comment: I already checked this post and tried.where to run this fsck. i did tried in my system and lost all data and reinstalled my os.

Comment: the command should be something like `hfsck example.dmg`

Comment: I runned this command in my mac 
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /PATH/TO/APPLICATION
 Then it stopped showing me the pop-up, whether to open or not to open . but how can i include this in my dmg itself, so that customer who downloaded will not get this security check popup. As i want my dmg to be shown as more secured one. And also i wanted to know whether every software downloaded in mac is asking this type of security check. please check this link too for further details    http://mactips.dwhoard.com/mactips/system/remove-quarantine